# Long PHP Requests Getting Dropped

Tags: php, symfony, timeout

I set up a local copy of my PHP app, which runs on the Symfony framework. It often processes requests which can take an hour to complete, due to socket communication with a C++ server. My remote server handles these fine, but my local server seems to be dropping the requests, never giving a response at all.

I have already set the configuration directive `max_execution_time` in my php.ini file. Are there any other settings that cause this behavior?

Comment: Did you check the settings for C++ too?

Comment: Yes, since the C++ server is running remotely, the setting are the same. The remote PHP server works well with it, so I suspect the local PHP configuration is the issue.

Comment: Possibly default_socket_timeout ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout

Comment: Great idea! I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not designed for long running requests. It's suppose to generate some output and return it back to the client.

I suggest you don't try long time processing during an http request, but return a **202 Accepted** response and delegate the processing to a background process.

You could leverage message queues for this. The http request would add a message to the queue, and there would be a set of consumers waiting for messages and processing them.

Comment: My remote server can consistently and reliably handle those long-running requests without any errors. I just want my local instance to behave the same way. Ideally I would make the changes you suggest, but I don't have time to change it if it's already working in production.